# Google Analytics: Test event tracking with test profile

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

With Universal analytics, what are the best practices in sending/testing data to a test profile?

I've included the tracking snippet before the `</head>` and the following:

```
window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXXXX-X'] = true;

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', {
  'cookieDomain': 'none'
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll usually handle this by always keeping the same code in production vs staging (aka remove the `ga-disable` and `cookieDomain` lines of your code snippet). I then create 2-5 different views in Google Analytics and filter them as:

- Default (include only production domains - eg: regex `^(www\.)?example\.com$`)
- Raw Data (no filters)
- Test Site (inlude only test domains - eg: exact `test.example.com`)
- Staging Site (include only test domains - eg: exact `staging.example.com`)
- Admin Site (include only admin domain - eg: exact `admin.example.com`)

Under Profile >> Filters there are predefined filters and custom filters. Use a predefined include `Traffic to the Domain` for all of the above.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. How does that workflow work when I am testing locally (i.e. localhost)?

Comment: Install the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) and/or [map something other than localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/how-to-edit-your-hosts-file-on-a-mac) and use that url instead (e.g., `dev.example.com`)